# how to take tree roots in a DFS forest?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

> A DFS starting at some vertex v explores the graph by building up a
> tree that contains all vertices that are reachable from v and all
> edges that are used to reach these vertices. We call this tree a DFS
> tree. A complete DFS exploring the full graph (and not only the part
> reachable from a given vertex v) builds up a collection of trees, or
> forest, called a DFS forest.

If I have a directed graph and I need to find the roots of these trees that are part of the dfs forest, do I have to modify the dfs algorithm to do this?

Comment: @ravenspoint yes my graph is directed can you explain to me with an example the speech of the edges because i think that's the point.

Comment: What do you mean by "speech of the edges"?

Comment: @ravenspoint i've done, i think that i can find all the nodes in the graph that have out edges but no in edges but i didn't understand how this is related to the forest of trees

Comment: A root is a node with no in-edges.  If a node has an in-edge it cannot be a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the roots of the trees in a directed graph, loop over the nodes and list any that have out edges but no in edges

Like this:

[image]

Comment: so I could do at first a simple dfs to see all the nodes that are reachable from the initial source and discard them, and then for the other nodes that I have left I have to check if this node has arcs in then the discard otherwise it means that it is a root .
did I get it right?
how can I do this by analyzing the adjacency list also in pseudocode or an idea on how to approach is fine.

Comment: here there is only a root because if i start the visit on on the bottom node I am able to inspect the whole graph. but if i have disconnected node. but if I have nodes disconnected from the graph or nodes that are connected to the main source I need to connect them to it from the other direction..

Comment: so I have to find the nodes that are not reachable from the main source and connect them to it.

Comment: Just do a search for the nodes with no in edges.  Third time I have told you this.

Comment: How can I check the nodes that have arcs that come out but no arcs that come in?

Comment: To answer that question I need to know how you are modelling the graph, storing the vertices and edges.  Are you using a graph theory library, or are you writing your own code from scratch?  You need to clarify your question and provide the details that would let us answer.  Posting a one sentence question allows only a one sentence answer.

Comment: ok it's clear I just wanted an idea on how to implement it but obviously you don't know how I created my class so you can't help me. Maybe I'll ask a separate question with all the code for this. Thanks